# How to apply REPLACE function with a range given by regex expression in Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, replace

I need to know how to apply `REPLACE` function with a range given by regex expression in Postgres SQL. (8 and 9)

eg :

```
SELECT REPLACE('HB2|HED/94412', 'H', '_') // gives _B2|_ED/94412
SELECT REPLACE('HB2|HED/94412', '[A-Z]', '_') // gives HB2|HED/94412
```

My regex for ideal scenario is [\|\*\/] used in WHERE clause as follows
.

```
SELECT * from myschema.mytable WHERE (REPLACE(hcode, '[\\|\\*\\/]', '_') = 'HB2_JED_94412' ) limit 1
```

Comment: Use `regexp_replace` function.

Comment: Thank you but it says, 
SQL error:
ERROR:  function regexp_replace("unknown", "unknown", "unknown") does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I noted this works.

```
SELECT translate('HB2|HED/94412', '[|/*]', '____')
```

But need to find the catches in there.
Rereferences : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html